# "import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader" Error

Tags: java, xml, csv, import, opencsv

I'm making a java program for converting from CSV file type to XML file type , I needed to import "open CSV" but when I write
 "import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader; " It's being underlined with red , and there's error telling me that " package au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader doesn't exist " , I downloaded "open csv-3.3" and I added it to the libraries using netbeans , but nothing changed , BTW the same error is happening with "au.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;" , there were some questions nearly similar to mine , but I didn't find an appropriate solution for the problem , so if anybody have a solution for the problem and the way of how to apply it to the code that will be nice ... and here are some lines" from my code ...

```
package fr.megiste.test;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

import au.com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class CsvToxml2 {     

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String startFile = "start.csv";
        String outFile = "out.xml";

        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(startFile));
            String[] line = null;

            String[] header = reader.readNext();

            List out = new ArrayList();

       while((line = reader.readNext())!=null){
                List<String[]> item = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                    String[] keyVal = new String[2];
                    String string = header[i];
                    String val = line[i];
                    keyVal[0] = string;
                    keyVal[1] = val;
                    item.add(keyVal);
                }
                out.add(item);
            }

            XStream xstream = new XStream();
```

Answer (score 7):

From opencsv 3.1 and later the packages were refactored to com.opencsv.   So CSVReader is in com.opencsv.CSVReader